# So is everything an expression in F#?

Tags: f#, unit-type

I am looking at the following F# line

```
for i = 0 to i=10 do
   Console.WriteLine("Hello")
```

An I am wondering that isn't the above line a statement as opposed to an expression?

Shouldn't everything be an expression in F#?

Comment: How do you define the words "statement" and "expression"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already said, every syntactical construct in F# is an *expression*. F# does not distinguish between statements and expressions (and so I'd say that the WikiPedia quote posted by Robert is a bit misleading - F# does not *have* statements).

<sup>Actually, the above is not fully true, because some constructs in F# computation expressions such as `let!` are not *expressions*, but we can ignore that.</sup>

What does that mean? In C#, the syntax of `for` and method calls is defined something like this:

```
statement  := foreach(var v in <expression>) <statement>
            | { <statement> ... <statement> }
            | <expression>;
            | (...)

expression := <expression>.<ident>(<expression>, ..., <expression>)
            | <literal>
            | <expression> + <expression>
            | (...)
```

This is very simplified, but it should give you the idea - a statement is something that does not evaluate to a value. It can be `foreach` loop (other loops), a statement block (with multiple statements) or an expression with semicolon (where the result of the expression is `void` or is ignored). An expression is, for example, method call, primitive literal (string, int) or a binary operator.

This means that you cannot write certain things in C# - for example, the argument of method call cannot be a statement (because statements do not evaluate to a value!)

On the other hand, in F#, everything is an expression. This means there is just a single syntactic category:

```
expression := for v in <expression> do <expression>
            | <expression>; <expression>
            | <expression>.<ident>(<expression>, ..., <expression>)
            | <literal>
            | <expression> + <expression>
            | (...)
```

This means that in F# all syntactic constructs are expressions, including `for` and other loops. The body of `for` is also an expression, but it would not make sense if the expression evaluated to some value (i.e. `42`), so the types require that the result of the body is `unit` (which does not carry any information). Similarly, the first expression in sequencing (`<expr>; <expr>`) should return `unit` - the result of sequencing is the result of the second expression.

This makes the language simpler and more uniform, but you can write some odd things:

```
let x = (for i in 0 .. 10 do printfn "%d" i); 42
```

This will print numbers from `0` to `10` and then define a value `x` to be `42`. The assignment is a sequencing of expressions (`<expr>; <expr>`) where the first one is `for` loop (that has a type `unit`, because it does not evaluate to anything) and the second one is `42`, which evaluates to 42.

Comment: "every syntactical construct in F# is an expression". Patterns are an obvious counterexample.

Comment: Total noob here but why let! Is not an expression? It is defined as an expression and to me it works as such, is a binding, removing syntactic sugar is returning a function with  everything thats below it and the arg of the comp exp, isn’t it?

Answer (score 4):

> Every statement in F#, including if statements and loops, is a
>   composable expression with a definite return type.
>   Functions and expressions that do not return any value have a return
>   type of unit.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: IIRC, in this code the return value of `Console.WriteLine("Hello")` will be the F# equiv of `void`, and the return value of the for loop will be the value of it's last expression (again, `void` in this case)

Comment: So you can do: `Console.WriteLine(for i = 0 to i=10 do foo(i))` ? Which will print nothing. Except for `foo(i)` side-effect.

Comment: @leppie - the code should be `Console.WriteLine(for i = 0 to 10 do foo(i))` but is otherwise correct.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Thanks, I was just copy/pasting from above ;p

Answer (score 0):

In languages like F# statements are just expressions that return the value `()` of type `unit`. As the `unit` type has only one value it conveys no information so returning the value of type unit is saying "if I'm doing anything then it is by way of a side effect" like printing to the console or writing to disk.

Note that not everything is an expression in F#. Type definitions are not expressions. Patterns are not expressions. And so on...